# What is the difference between Service-Oriented Computing and Service-Oriented Architecture?

Tags: terminology, soa, soc

I've found this:

> The Service-Oriented Computing (SOC)
>   paradigm refers to the set of
>   concepts, principles, and  methods
>   that represent computing in
>   Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA) in
>   which software  applications are
>   constructed based on independent
>   component services with standard
>   interfaces.

Is Service-Oriented Computing the mean and Service-Oriented Architecture the result? Or, are they the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

> Service-oriented computing represents
>   a new generation distributed computing
>   platform. As such, it encompasses many
>   things, including its own design
>   paradigm and design principles, design
>   pattern catalogs, pattern languages, a
>   distinct architectural model, and
>   related concepts, technologies, and
>   frameworks.

So, Service-Oriented Computing is a paradigm and Service Oriented Architecture is an architectural model which allows interoperability, re-usability, loose-coupling of its components.

More information: [What is SOA](http://serviceorientation.com/whatissoa/fundamental_design_terminology_and_concepts)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that service oriented computing, *if the industry would agree to such a term*, would amount for the **layer of the SOA approach that deals with realizing core services**. The idea seems to be this:

Service Oriented Computation deals with implementing the core services, and Service Oriented Composition/Management about managerial tasks (WS-BPEL, WS-CDL), and Service Oriented Communication would relate to message routing (WS-Addressing, WS-ReliableDelivery, et.c.,)
Also, fundamental service-oriented-computation ideas appear to be extensions to distributed computing, and the implementations domain-specific.